Unresolved symbol: different behavior in QMake and MSBuild
I have three projects: A, B, and C. Project A is an executable/DLL, and projects B and C are static libraries. There is a function Add(int, int) in B, which is called by A. The implementation of Add depends on a function AddImpl from C.
As per my understanding of C++, I only need to link B when compiling A because all the contents of AddImpl should have been copied when compiling B. This works correctly in Visual Studio 2019/2022, but it doesn't work in Qt Creator, even though the compiler is MSVC in both cases.
Is this a bug in QMake, or am I missing something in C++?
Qt project:
A.pro
QT -= gui
CONFIG += c++11
SOURCES += A.cpp
LIBS += -Lpath/to/B -lB
INCLUDEPATH += path/to/Bheader

A.cpp
#include <B.h>
int main() {
    Add(1, 2);
    return 0;
}

B.pro
QT -= gui
CONFIG += c++11
SOURCES += B.cpp
LIBS += -Lpath/to/C -lC
INCLUDEPATH += path/to/Cheader

B.h
int Add(int, int);

B.cpp
#include <C.h>
#include "B.h"
int Add(int a, int b) {
    return AddImpl(a, b);
}

C.pro
QT -= gui
CONFIG += c++11
SOURCES += C.cpp

// C.h
int AddImpl(int, int);

// C.cpp
int AddImpl(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}

In Visual Studio, I set it up by right click on project, going to Properties/Librarian and set C.lib to 'Additional Dependencies' and set output path of C to 'Additional Library Directories'. The 'Additional Dependencies' of A is under Properties/Linker/General and the 'Additional Library Directories' is under Properties/Linker/Input.
Also, I noticed that qmake uses 'link.exe' in link stage to compile static lib while msbuild use 'lib.exe' to do the same thing. I don't know if this can explain the different behavior.

Please show a [mre] of your qmake file

Note that qmake is pretty much deprecated (it's not been deprecated yet but qt themselves don't use it anymore and aren't developing it any further), you'll probably be better off with cmake

Static libraries don't contain transitive dependencies, you always have to link to dependencies directly. Visual studio is likely detecting (or you've told it but forgotten) that the static library is built in your project and linking to the project rather than just directly to the library

To add to @AlanBirtles comment - MSBuild can/will detect transitive project dependencies.
